# How can I force Thunderbird to download mail not marked as new?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, pop3

My ISP uses Gmail for their email handling - but, sorry Gmail lovers, I don't like it. I much prefer a desktop mail client; Thunderbird specifically at present.

However, I've had a computer failure and really need - if at all possible - to be able to download the entirety of my Gmail folder via POP from my ISP's mail servers. I know about IMAP, I know about the webmail interface, but they won't do what I need unfortunately - which I accept is an odd requirement!

The mail is, as far as I can tell, still on the server but Thunderbird won't download it because it's not marked as new. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You *can* download all messages over IMAP; just drag and drop them to a local folder. You can even upload them to another IMAP server. Also, *OfflineIMAP*, *getmail*, *fetchmail* for making automated local backups.

Comment: IMAP is also cached locally, or at least can be in Thunderbird. I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Grawity for pointing me in the right direction, but I've now found the even better option - 'Backing up your mail with POP'. http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34030&topic=1668962

(Which seems to keep locking on individual messages and so requires rather more hand-holding than is ideal, but never mind... It's progress.)

Answer (score 5):

Prefix the username with `recent:` to activate the ["recent" mode](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=47948), which will download *all* mail from the **last 30 days**.

Comment: +1 Did not know about recent mode. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To "force" a re-download of all IMAP messages in Thunderbird; try renaming / deleting popstate.dat per [this wiki](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Popstate.dat) I just used this method on TB v17 to download several years of emails. I first moved my current inbox for that account to a temp folder and then after the emails downloaded I copied them all back in and ran a duplicate check.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it. Be careful: You'll need to reset your account parameters!

- Transfer your present inbox to a local folder
- Then delete the email account corresponding to this inbox (Tools » Account parameter)
- Then re-open this same account, brand new.

Thunderbird will download all messages to the new setup account.